# Sending a jsonWebToken with every request to a certain webpage

Tags: javascript, authentication, web, browser

I am developing a web app and having some problems with the authentication, for which I'm using json web tokens. The app is supposed to be closed, so it should ask for your credentials even when you try to access its main page. However, I can't figure out how I could send a token just when entering, say, http://localhost:3000/ into the address bar. I thought about it and figured that it would be simplest to just configure the browser such that it will store that token and send it along with EVERY request to the domain name of the app (ex. http://localhost:3000/... will send the token, whatever ... is). I searched the web, but didn't find any answers that suited what I need.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a Single Page Application (SPA) or a server side web application?

In Single Page Applications you can typically retrieve the main page anonymously and the JavaScript in the page-load event handler triggers the authentication flow. The returned token is then sent **explicitly** via JavaScript with each request made to the server.

In server side web applications (like ASP.NET MVC), the authentication flow is triggered when the user navigates to the main page by redirecting them to an authentication endpoint. Once the user authenticates successfully, a cookie is sent back which is **automatically** sent with each request by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the technology you are using. If you are using Javascript(AngularJS, Vuejs or even React) on the frontend, then you can send a token via a header or query String like so:

```
function createRequest(){

    var request = new Request();  // create an actual request from your whatever library you are using

    request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token')); // add the header

    return request; 
}
```

So for every request made to the server, the token is attached as a header.

If you are using a server-side technology like PHP...You can use [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) Client to make a request and attach the token to every request. A sample implementation of that will look like this:

```
    /**
     * Instantiate Guzzle Client and prepare request for http operations
     * @return none
     */
    private function prepareRequest()
    {
        $this->client = new Client(['base_uri' => self::baseURL]);
    }
    /**
     * Perform a GET request
     * @param  string $relativeUrl
     * @return none
     */
    private function performGetRequest($relativeUrl)
    {
        $this->response = $this->client->request('GET', $relativeUrl, [
            'auth' => [$this->publicKey, $this->accessToken]
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Perform a POST request
     * @param  string $relativeUrl
     * @param  array $data
     * @return none
     */
    private function performPostRequest($relativeUrl, $data)
    {
        $this->response = $this->client->request('POST', $relativeUrl, [
            'auth' => [$this->publicKey, $this->accessToken],
            'form_params' => $data
        ]);
    }
```

The token key is attached to every request as a value to the `auth` key!

If you are looking for additional resources or complete code implementation, you might want to check out the following posts:

- https://auth0.com/blog/creating-your-first-real-world-angular-2-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api-and-everything-in-between/
- https://auth0.com/blog/create-your-first-ember-2-dot-0-app-from-authentication-to-calling-an-api/

You can also find posts about Aurelia and Vuejs RESTful API implementation together with authentication.

I hope this information helps. Cheers!